# How to change default location of created entities ? (php bin/console make:entity)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I want to change default location of entities in Symfony4: when I launch the command `php bin/console make:entity`, it automatically creates a new file in the namespace **App\Entity**. 
I want to create it in another namespace, like **App\Appli\Entity** by example.

I have already tried to change the following files without any changes.

- doctrine.yaml
- EntityGenerator.php

I also threw an eye on `make:entity --help`, but it doesn't seem that we can set any path.

In the *doctrine.yaml*, I've added this code:

```
mappings:
   Appli:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Appli'
        prefix: 'App\Appli\Entity'
        alias: Appli
```

I want to create a new Entity in the folder  **src/Appli/Entity**  with the command line `php bin/console make:entity`, but it always created it in the folder  **src/Entity**  !!

Answer (score 4):

From the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#configuration)

Configure the root namespace

```
# config/packages/dev/maker.yaml
maker:
    root_namespace: 'App\Appli\Entity'
```

Comment: Yes, the bundle doesn't need any configuration to work so the recipe does not create the file when you require the package, create it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, it worked!

In fact I have two folders where I want to create entities: **Appli** and **Dev**

```
src
  |- Appli
     |- Entity
       ....
  |- Dev
     |- Entity
       ....
```

So do I have to modify the *maker.yaml* when I want to add an entity in Appli or in Dev, or is there any other method?

Comment: Yes, Symfony is now [bundle less](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-monolith-vs-micro.html) so you have to modify the `maker.yaml` every time

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without re-configuring, but with a slightly different structure like `App\Entity\Appli` and `App\Entity\Dev` by specifing the sub directory in the command's prompt for Class name.

```
$ php bin/console make:entity 

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. BravePizza):
> Appli\Thing

created: src/Entity/Appli/Thing.php
created: src/Repository/Appli/ThingRepository.php
```

The above entity is created with `namespace App\Entity\Appli;`

```
$ php bin/console make:entity

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. TinyChef):
> Dev\Thing

created: src/Entity/Dev/Thing.php
created: src/Repository/Dev/ThingRepository.php
```

The above entity is created with `namespace App\Entity\Dev;`